# A function that converts base 10 to binary using stacks to solve it

Tags: c++

So I'm asked to write this function in C++ that converts a base 10 integer and prints the integer's binary equivalent 
I should use a stack to solve the problem also I'm not allowed to use recursion in my function.

Here's what i think:
While doing the conversion i should start pushing the 1s and 0s into a stack accordingly , the order will be reversed (i think) so i will have to move them to another stack to have the right order after doing that i can start taking the top of the copied stack and print it then pop it to get the next number since the function is not a member function and i cant access the members randomly .

I need to know if my method is right and I'm not exactly sure how to do the conversion.

Comment: That's what you think, but what have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried implementing it? If not, what is stopping you, and what have you tried to overcome it? If so, please post the code, any error messages or output, as well as what you would expect the output to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number;
    cin>>number;
    stack<int> binary;
    while(number>1)
    {
        binary.push(number%2);
        number /= 2;
    }
    cout<<1;
    while(!binary.empty())
    {
        cout<<binary.top();
        binary.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Tip:

1. Whatever recursion can do, loops can also do.
2. If you have an idea, always try to implement it first. You can still ask questions if you fail.